# Is there any way to optimize this function and make it faster?

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

is there a way to optimize this? It is taking way too long to run

```
let counter2 = ref 0

let rec s2 num = 
  counter2 := !counter2 + 1;
  match num with
  | 0 -> 1
  | 1 -> 2
  | _ -> (((((6*num)-3) * (s2 (num-1))) / (num+1))) - (((num-2)* (s2 (num-2))/(num+1)))
```

Comment: Too long to compile, or too long to run? Also it would help if you format and structure your code a little better. I assume you're allowed to use variables?

Comment: Too long to run, and yes, I will try to format it better with variables

Comment: This is a fibonacci-style function. The classic way to optimize is to pass previous values of the function (for smaller n) as parameters. This can make a huge difference.

Comment: The thing is how do i put them in parameters

Comment: I will show how to do it for fibonacci. You can find this in many textbooks.

Comment: `(((((6*num)-3) * (s2 (num-1))) / (num+1))) - (((num-2)* (s2 (num-2))/(num+1)))` has a lot of extra parens that makes this hard to read. OCaml's [operator precedence](https://ocaml.org/manual/expr.html) makes many of these unnecessary.

Comment: It's possible to solve your function in linear time using dynamic programming, memoization in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the highly recursive definition of the Fibonacci sequence:

```
let rec fib n = 
  if n < 2 then n 
  else fib (n - 2) + fib (n - 1)
```

Here is the not so recursive definition of the Fibonacci sequence.

```
let nfib n =
  let rec helper pprev prev i =
    if i = n then
      pprev + prev
    else
      helper prev (pprev + prev) (i + 1)
  in
  if n < 2 then n 
  else helper 0 1 2
```

Here is a function for timing things:

```
let time f x =
  let st = Unix.gettimeofday () in
  let res = f x in
  Printf.printf "%f seconds\n" (Unix.gettimeofday () -. st);
  res
```

Here are times for the `fib` and `nfib` functions:

```
# time fib 42;;
7.694294 seconds
- : int = 267914296
# time nfib 42;;
0.000002 seconds
- : int = 267914296
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's clean this up a bit. This is just your approach, but tidied up by taking advantage of order of operations and binding some names to subexpressions. I've also used `incr counter2` rather than `counter2 := !counter2 + 1`.

```
let counter2 = ref 0

let rec s2 num = 
  incr counter2;
  match num with
  | 0 -> 1
  | 1 -> 2
  | _ -> 
    let s2' = s2 (num - 1) in
    let s2'' = s2 (num - 2) in
    let num' = num + 1 in
    (6 * num - 3) * s2' / num' - (num-2) * s2'' / num'
```

Now the efficiency issue with this code is that `s2` gets called more than it needs to. If we evaluate `s2 4` for instance:

```
s2 4
  s2 3
    s2 2
      s2 1
      s2 0
    s2 1
  s2 2
    s2 1
    s2 0
```

For `s2 5`:

```
s2 5
  s2 4
    s2 3
      s2 2
        s2 1 
        s2 0
      s2 1
    s2 2
      s2 1
      s2 0
  s2 3
    s2 2
      s2 1
      s2 0
    s2 1
```

So there are 9 and 15 calls respectively to `s2` in those two calls. But how many `unique` calls are there?  5 and 6, respectively.

If we *cache* the results of these calculations in something like a [map](https://v2.ocaml.org/api/Map.html), we can significantly reduce the complexity of the function, since map lookups are in a worst case situation O(log n).

We then just have to pass a map as an argument to the function and have the function either lookup the cached result, or calculate it and cache it, passing that cache along to the next call to avoid repeated calls.

"Hiding" this function inside an `s3` function allows us to make the map "invisible" to anyone calling `s3` and initialize it with the bindings for 0 and 1.

```
module M = Map.Make (Int)

let s3 num =
  let counter = ref 0 in
  let rec aux num map =
    incr counter;
    match M.find_opt num map with
    | Some v -> (v, map)
    | None ->
      let (s3', map') = aux (num - 1) map in
      let (s3'', map'') = aux (num - 2) map' in
      let num' = num + 1 in
      let result = (6 * num - 3) * s3' / num' - (num-2) * s3'' / num' in
      (result, M.add num result map'')
  in
  (!counter, fst @@ aux num @@ M.(empty |> add 0 1 |> add 1 2))
```

If we call `s2 10_000`, expect to be waiting a very long time. Calling `s3 10_000` is almost instant. Of course, this will overflow the `int` type, but it'll do so *quickly*.

```
# s3 10_000;;
- : int * int = (19999, -159516254014960)
```